# jQuery `val()` on input element returning empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a table of elements in HTML, and then when an edit button (which would be next to the row you would want to edit) is pressed it would turn the text elements into `<input>` elements.

However, after you enter values into the input fields and press the edit button again (saving your changes), it is *supposed* to make the original text elements contain the ones entered into the input field.

I have also tried using the `text()` function, and that also returns empty.

This is my HTML...

```html
<table>
    <tr id='0'>
        <td id='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Title</td>
        <td id='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0 mins</td>
        <td id='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Genre</td>
        <td id='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">[]</td>
        <td id='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0</td>

        <td>
            <button id="editButton" style="background-color:#ADD8E6" />&#128393;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my jQuery...

```js
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === "editButton") {
        $(this).parent().parent().children("#editable").html("<input type='text' id='editable'/>");

        $(this).attr("id", "saveable")
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().children("#editable").each(function(i) {
            $(this).html("<td>" + $(this).val() + "</td>")
        })

        $(this).attr("id", "editButton")
    }
});
```

I have been testing this on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajecdm5n/1/.

Also, if there are any improvements I can make, please do tell me.

Comment: IDs need to be unique, so that is the first thing you need to fix here.

Comment: where you are write coding for saving?

Comment: @CBroe Would I then just loop through all of the children() to change each element?

Comment: @Vel I am just using this to test editing a table's elements. The saving is seperate for now.

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pymftrdw/ You are looking like this?

Comment: Basically yes, except I want it to look like the starting table but with the new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, an `id` should be a **unique** identifier for one element on the page, whereas you have several with the same ID. If you need many elements to have the same identifier then it's better to give them a `class` instead.

Next, your `#editable` elements are your `<td>` elements as well as your editable text field - so the actual rendered HTML assumedly looks like `<td id='editable'><input type='text' id='editable' />`. This is causing issues in your for loop because you are setting the `html` on the `<td>` first - which removes the `<input>` - then trying to loop onto the input. In addition, `<td>` doesn't have a `.val()`, so this is why your method call is empty.

You may also wish to consider using data properties to store whether it's an edit button or not, as I think changing the ID can be problematic.

Perhaps something like this may be better?

```html
<table>
    <tr id='0'>
        <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Title</td>
        <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0 mins</td>
        <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Genre</td>
        <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">[]</td>
        <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0</td>

        <td>
            <button class="editButton" style="background-color:#ADD8E6" />&#128393;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
$(".editButton").click(function() {
    const btn = $(this);
    const row = btn.parent().parent();

    if (btn.data("editing") === "true") {
        row.children(".editable").each(function(i) {
            const editField = $(":first-child", $(this)); //only element is input
            $(this).html("<td>" + editField.val() + "</td>")
        });
        btn.data("editing", "false");
    } else {
        row.children(".editable").html("<input type='text' class='editable-field'/>"); //give it a different class so we can look it up by that if needed
        btn.data("editing", "true");
    }
});
```

Comment: When trying to save the changes using this I am getting a `TypeError: editField.val is not a function`.

Comment: Ah my bad, it's been a while since I jQuery-ed! I'd given you a raw `HTMLElement` there intead of one wrapped in jQuery, I'll update now

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#editButton").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') === "editButton") {
    $(this).parent().parent().children(".editable").html("<input name='test[]' type='text' id='editable' value=''/>");
    
    $(this).attr("id", "saveable")
  } else {
    let Inputhtml ='';
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable input").each(function(i) {
    Inputhtml +="<td>" + $(this).val() + "</td>";
        //$(".testtable").html("<td>" + $(this).val() + "</td>")
    })
    $(".testtable").html(Inputhtml);
    $(this).attr("id", "editButton")
  }
});
```

```css
.table {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

.input {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 10px;
}

.td {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="testtable">
  <tr id='0'>
    <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Title</td>
    <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0 mins</td>
    <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">Genre</td>
    <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">[]</td>
    <td class='editable' style="border:1px solid #000;padding:7px">0</td>
    <td style="color:blue">0</td>
    <td>
      <button id="editButton"style="background-color:#ADD8E6"/>&#128393;
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background-color:#F08080"/>&#9932;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update fiddle link**

https://jsfiddle.net/pymftrdw/2/

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for, however I want it to look like the starting table but with the new values.

Comment: I didnt get you

Comment: Nevermind, I overlooked the Inputhtml. It works exactly as I want it to, thank you for the help!

Comment: Please check the update fiddle link